# How to column value as column name dynamicaly in oracle plsql query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need specific value of column as column name not to conversion row to column  by using following query with result

> Blockquote

```
 SELECT AAA.fin_year_quarter,AAA.GEOG_STATE_NAME,AAA.SKU_NAME,SUM(AAA.VALUE) 
     FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT dm.fin_year_quarter,FCPS.TERRITORY_SID,
                               DG.GEOG_STATE_NAME,dp.sku_name,
                               SUM(FCPS.PRIMARY_SALES_VALUE) AS VALUE
               FROM fact_chw_primary_sales FCPS,DIM_GEOGRAPHY
                     DG,dim_productdp,dim_month dm
               WHERE FCPS.TERRITORY_SID=DG.TERRITORY_SID
               and  fcps.product_sid=dp.product_sid
               and fcps.month_sid=dm.month_sid
               AND DM.MONTH_SID=5845
               GROUP BY FCPS.TERRITORY_SID,DG.GEOG_STATE_NAME,  
                       dp.sku_name,dm.fin_year_quarter
             )AAA
      GROUP BY AAA.GEOG_STATE_NAME,AAA.SKU_NAME,AAA.fin_year_quarter
      ORDER BY AAA.GEOG_STATE_NAME ASC, SUM(AAA.VALUE) DESC,AAA.SKU_NAME ASC;
```

The result of this query is :-

```
        FIN_YEAR_QUARTER GEOG_STATE_NAME   SKU_NAME    **SUM(AAA.VALUE)**
      **2015-2016-Q4**   DELHI-0801        PVPM0017G    4195295
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        RGPRM035G    3191880
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        RGPM0035G    1397599
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPR0017G    250369.5
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPM0180G    65248.22
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPM1000G    42258.18
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPS0380G    9272.4
```

But My requirement is like that as with above query :-

```
        FIN_YEAR_QUARTER GEOG_STATE_NAME   SKU_NAME   **2015-2016-Q4**
      **2015-2016-Q4**   DELHI-0801        PVPM0017G    4195295
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        RGPRM035G    3191880
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        RGPM0035G    1397599
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPR0017G    250369.5
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPM0180G    65248.22
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPM1000G    42258.18
        2015-2016-Q4     DELHI-0801        PVPS0380G    9272.4
```

For quarter 3rd result will be as :-

```
 "FIN_YEAR_QUARTER" "GEOG_STATE_NAME"  "SKU_NAME"   **"2015-2016-Q3"**

  **2015-2016-Q3**   BOMBAY-0802      PVPM00173G  5195292
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        RGPRM0353G    4191881
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        RGPM00353G    39759
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        PVPR00173G    2503.5
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        PVPM01803G    652.22
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        PVPM10003G    14225.18
    2015-2016-Q3     BOMBAY-0802        PVPS03803G    927200.4
```

This Result are coming the  bases of DM.MONTH_SID please suggest Its need full.

Comment: Is the only difference really the final column name?

Comment: What if `FIN_YEAR_QUARTER` has more than one value?

Comment: I'm thinking the only way you are going to get a dynamic header is to do an execute immediate to create a view and then select from that view. but again as Aleksej asked what if fin_year_quarter has more than one value.  and also can't your presentation layer just set the column headers to whatever it wants?

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff , Yes  only needs the column value as column name  can be change some time '2015-2016-Q3" or "2015-2016-Q2" in place  "2015-2016-Q4"  this quarterly value so in one time only one value.

Comment: Thank you @"Aleksej", Yes, FIN_YEAR_QUARTER  has more then one value  but in one time , it will come one value, in this query we are trying to fetch quarterly value  like  "2015-2016-Q4" means 4rth quarter ,2015-2016-Q3 means  3rd quarter etc.  So my question is when any changes happen  in FIN_YEAR_QUARTER column that comes as column name  in place of  "SUM(AAA.VALUE)".

Comment: If you're going to have a single date in FIN_YEAR_QUARTER, what's the point in calling the final column the name of that date rather than something more descriptive like, for example, total_sales_amount? Or, if you must have the value column called the date, why bother with FIN_YEAR_QUARTER?

Comment: thank you @Boneist, This is need full because client wants to show the value  quarterly in reports that is why i want to use as header of column.

Comment: What client program are you using to display this information?  The best solution is almost certainly done with that program, and not in regular SQL.  (But if this must really be done in a single SQL statement, there is a way to do it.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't have `2015-2016-Q4` as column name. Since it is starting with number and contains hyphens in between, you will encounter the below error :

```
    ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

However, you can use `column name` as `Q4_2015_2016`

Try Something like this using Dynamic SQL -

```
     DECLARE 
     sql_query varchar(400);
     Var1 varchar2(20);
     BEGIN
     select  distinct 
     (case  FIN_YEAR_QUARTER when '2015-2016-Q4' then 'Q4_2015_2016' else 'NOT Q4' end )
     into Var1 
     from SALES;
     sql_query := ' select GEOG_STATE_NAME,FIN_YEAR_QUARTER,value as  ' || var1 || '
                    from SALES ' ; 
    dbms_output.put_line('Generated SQL is  =>  ' ||chr(10)||chr(13)|| sql_query);
    END;
```

**Pl/sql Block Output:**

[image: DBMS_OUTPUT]

**output of the query generated above:**

[image: OUTPUT]

PS: Replace your query in the `SQL_QUERY`

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the end user tool. If you are using Oracle BI-publisher you can group the data as per 1st column. And then use the value in the 1st column value as heading for the 4th.